# How to link playing card values to images in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can already output the card values and I have 52 card images in assets. How can I combine each card value to its corresponding image?

For example, if I randomly output one card from the deck it would show the corresponding image to it.

Here's the card deck class:

```
export default class cardDeck extends React.Component{
constructor(){
super();
this.deck = [];
this.reset();
this.shuffle();
}

reset(){

this.deck = [];

const suits = ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds'];
const values = ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King'];

for (let suit in suits) {
for (let value in values) {
  this.deck.push(`${values[value]} of ${suits[suit]}`);
}
}
}

shuffle(){
const { deck } = this;
let m = deck.length, i;

while(m){
i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

[deck[m], deck[i]] = [deck[i], deck[m]];
}

return this;
}
}
```

In the game class, I just call the shuffle function and then render one card from the array randomly, and there, I would like it to show the cards corresponding image instead of just the text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so one approach you could take is to name the card images like `aceofhearts.jpg, 2ofhearts.jpg, 3ofspades.jpg` etc

Then in the code you could do something like this wherever you're displaying the images

```
//remove spaces - could do this in a loop to get all the cards
let card = deck[0].split(' ').join('')

//make sure to set this to your image path
let imagePath = `../assets/images/${card}.jpg`

//JSX
<Image source={require(imagePath)} />
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the error is: invalid call at line 19: require(imagePath). It works if I define the card = 'jack of hearts' but that doesn't help. I have checked also that just by printing deck[0] it outputs the string which corresponds to the image name.

Comment: @MikkoKettunen and you updated that path `../assets/images/${card}.jpg` to the actual path to your assets folder? Also, the image files should be named like 2ofhearts.jpg so when you use card = deck[0].split(' ').join('') you'll also get something like 2ofhearts

Comment: @MikkoKettunen you said " It works if I define the card = 'jack of hearts' " so I'm wondering if your filenames also have spaces in them? I suppose that would be fine if they do just remove the `.split(' ').join('')` and you'll get the name with spaces.